# Protocolo NBR 14522

Tags: c, linux, serial

Estou desenvolvendo software para comunicação com medidor via porta serial, e estou conseguindo enviar os comandos via serial, segue os códigos:

```
int serial_open(const char *device, int baud)
{   
    struct termios tio;
    int fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

    memset (&tio, 0, sizeof tio);

    /*
     * Note that `baud' is not an actual baud rate number;
     * it's one of the constants (e. g., `B9600') in <termios.h>
     */
    tcgetattr(fd, &tio);

    cfsetospeed(&tio, baud);
    cfsetispeed(&tio, baud);

    tio.c_cflag = (tio.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
    // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
    // as \000 chars
    tio.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
    tio.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                        // no canonical processing
    tio.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
    tio.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
    tio.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    tio.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

    tio.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                        // enable reading
    tio.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
    tio.c_cflag |= 0;                   //parity
    tio.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tio.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; 

    tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tio);
    sleep(1);   //Waiting for set serial port

    return fd;
}

uint8_t serial_recv(int fd)
{
    uint8_t byte;
    read(fd, &byte, sizeof byte);
    usleep(1000);

    return byte;
}

void serial_send(int fd, uint8_t byte)
{
    write(fd, &byte, sizeof byte);
    usleep(1000);   //Waiting write byte
}
```

Entretanto o protocolo de comunicação diz que tenho que colocar 0x01 na saída serial e esse vai ser considerado se estável por 1 segundo, após isso recebo ENQ e posso enviar o comando.

Entretanto:

```
serial_send(fd, 0x01);
sleep(1);
```

Isso não esta sendo reconhecido pelo medidor, acho que pode ser alguma configuração a abertura da porta ou estou entendendo erroneamente o protocolo?

Setup da serial 9600 8N1
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o que é esse "1 lógico" na documentação ? é realmente um byte de dados 0x01 ? não seria um sinal elétrico do tipo RTS (request to send) ?

Comment: Conseguiu desenvolver o protocolo ?

Comment: @Joao sim, fiz a implantação e o sistema esta em funcionamento em vários ativos.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o problema a um [mcve]. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).